# IE 9 getting hanged up with data jQuery data table 1.1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am using jQuery datatable1.1.9, it's working very slowly and getting stuck with IE9. I want to improve its performance. I am dealing with 9000-10000 records so please any suggestion help me..

Comment: did you try in other browser?..

Comment: yes its working with all browser and with IE 10 and higher.. its working fine but not working with IE 9... please help.. me its urgent

Comment: You might want to take a look at all your add ons/accelerators (tools/manage add ons), and try disabling them all. Then enable them one by one until the problem returns. That will tell you which one is the problem (if it is add ons)..

Comment: no its not add ons problem ... I am checking this with my team.. so all r facing the same issue..

Comment: The fact that it's urgent for you is completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: ok ...but m searching for solution..

Comment: You could try ajax loading the table content for ie9: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE versions 9 and below are notorious for problems with table rendering speed. The usual suggestions are:

- Set the table-layout CSS attribute to fixed on the table.
- Explicitly define col objects for each column.
- Set the WIDTH attribute on each col.

I'm not sure which if any of these could be achieved with datatables though.